# Polymer build path prefix for github pages

Tags: git, polymer, polymer-1.0, github-pages, polymer-starter-kit

When using `polymer build` to build my Polymer app, is it possible to add a prefix to all file urls? As when I deploy this to `gh-pages`, it serves it under the sub-directory of the repo-name.

So in essence, currently it generates `/bower-elements/some-element/some-element.html` where it should be `/repo-name/bower-elements/some-element/some-element.html`.

Thanks!

Comment: See 
 https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/273
 https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/pull/336#issuecomment-245597415

Comment: Thanks for that, although they seem to be addressing a different problem where the project files are in a sub-directory, my problem is that it is in the root directory, but I'd like to host it in a sub-directory.